# Determine missing opening grouping character and add it

Tags: regex, replace

Slight change to the answer given works great! `dropcaps">([a-zA-Z])</span>([^“]*)”`

---

I'm going through and editing some ePubs and I've got a series where the styles of how the ePubs were published don't match. It'll bother me (and I'd like all my things to look the same), so I've started going through with Sigil and replacing covers, separating some stuff, and generally getting the second book to match the first book.

Now my problem is in the first book, if a chapter opened with a quote, it would do something like this:

```
<p class="nonindent"><span class="dropcaps">“T</span>his is a quote,” Rob wrote to all of StackOverflow.</p>
```

But the second book was completely different! I've moved some CSS rules over and used some regex to replace the way it was doing it, but now I've got a different problem:

```
<p class="nonindent"><span class="dropcaps">F</span>orget an opening quote mark,” somebody told the publisher, “It'll just look silly.”</p>
```

Now, instead of a nice large `“F` and normal the rest of the text, I've got just a large F (even though it's a quote). I rather like the look of it with the opening quote, and while I could go through each chapter and check and see, I've not read the book and I don't want to spoil anything for myself.

Is there a way I could find where the ones that are missing a `“` are and add it in?

There a few different cases:

```
<p class="nonindent"><span class="dropcaps">W</span>hoops,” only one quote.</p>

<p class="nonindent"><span class="dropcaps">F</span>orget an opening quote mark,” somebody told the publisher, “It'll just look silly.”</p>

<p class="nonindent"><span class="dropcaps">T</span>his is a regular sentence. “Fun times!”</p>

<p class="nonindent"><span class="dropcaps">T</span>his is a regular sentence. No quotes at all!</p>
```

It'll always be "dropcaps", so I had started with something like:

`dropcaps">([a-zA-Z])</span>(.*)”` and tried this from an answer `dropcaps">([a-zA-Z])</span>([^"]*)”`, but these will fail on the third example (where I don't need an opening `“`) because they will add a `“` when I don't need one.

Which would work if there were no other quotes in the line (like the first example), but in some cases (like the third example), there are! I need to know if there is a ” with NO “ before it in the line at all, which will be the case where it is missing. Is there a nice, clean way to do this with regex?

The same solution would work for lines with a missing opening ANY character (`<`, `(`, `[`, `{`), which I just realized. I'll search to see if I can find anything like that in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following regex as used in sed:

```
sed 's/dropcaps">\([a-zA-Z]\)<\/span>\([^“]*\)”/dropcaps">“\1<\/span>\2”/' < book2 > book2.fixed
```

Here, the snippet `\([a-zA-Z]\)` matches `[a-zA-Z]` and stores the match as `\1` to be used in the replacement pattern. The second `\([^"]*\)"` matches a sequence of characters except a quote that ends with a quote and stores that match as `\2`. The replacement then just uses these with an (open) quote in the correct place.

This solution assumes that in your second book, the three kinds of quotation marks: `", ”, “` are distinguished. The problems becomes much harder if this is not true.

Comment: `", ”, “` are all different. If they weren't I'd just go through and read the first sentence of every chapter. This doesn't work quite right in a different case (where it doesn't need a `“`, but there is a quote later in the line. Adding it to the question.

Comment: `dropcaps">\([a-zA-Z]\)<\/span>\([^“]*\)”` looks like it might be what I need. `[^“]` instead of `[^"]`.

Comment: Oops. You're right. I've fixed the answer with regards to your second comment. Digesting your first one ...

Comment: I should've just rewrote it to use a different character, all these quotes are bit insane!

Comment: Okay - I copied your four sentences as a test case and tried them out with the sed expression above. I think the correct action is for the first two cases to have an open quote inserted, with no such thing being done for the last two cases. This is indeed what I obtained with the sed command I fixed based on the second comment.

Comment: Yup, that's why you got the check!